# Pandas columns to rows with values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` like -

```
fileName     obj1   obj2   obj3   obj4
file_01.jpg  1      1      1
file_02.jpg         1      1
file_03.jpg  1      2             1
```

**Expected output**:

```
variable   value
obj1       2
obj2       4
obj3       2
obj4       1
```

**What did I try**?
`df.melt(value_vars=df.columns).groupby(['variable']).count()`

**Received output**:

```
variable   value
fileName   3
obj1       3
obj2       3
obj3       3
obj4       3
```

I also tried using `.pivot` and `.groupby`, but I was unable to attain my expected results.

**EDIT** : Edit to the 'expected output' - I need the sum of each column.
 ***Apologies to everyone who had answered before edit!***

Comment: re your edit to expected output, updated my answer from `inputdf.count()` to `inputdf.sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use column wise sum:

```
(
    df.set_index('fileName')
    .sum(0)
    .to_frame('value')
    .rename_axis('variable')
    .reset_index()
)

variable    value
0   obj1    2
1   obj2    4
2   obj3    2
3   obj4    1
```

Comment: I missed this solution was there, This is better

Comment: Thanks Allen! There were a fre empty strings in the DataFrame which I removed with `df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`. Your solution on top of that gave the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Input Data:

```
inputdf = pd.DataFrame({'obj1': [1,np.nan, 1], 'obj2': [1,1,2], 'obj3': [1,1,np.nan],  'obj4': [np.nan, np.nan, 1]})
```

Solution:

```
>>> inputdf.sum()
obj1    2.0
obj2    4.0
obj3    2.0
obj4    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Suppose I had empty strings like '' in the place of empty cells, any method to clear them or change them to np.nan?

Comment: Thanks Max! I got the the solution with `df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the columns that wants the results on & then do a `count` on those columns.

```
df[df.filter(like='obj').columns].count().reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'variable', 0 : 'value'})
```

**Output**

```
   variable     value
0   obj1        2
1   obj2        3
2   obj3        2
3   obj4        1
```

Comment: thanks @moys, but the column names are not subject to be just obj. They can be anything. I used obj1, obj2, etc. as example.

Comment: then you can use `df.iloc[, 1: ]` instead of `df.filter(like='obj').columns` with the rest the code as is.

Answer (score 0):

"One liner" (probably a little convoluted):

```
(
    df[[i for i in df.columns if 'obj' in i]]
    .stack()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .drop('level_0', axis=1)
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'variable', 0:'value',})
    .groupby('variable')
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  variable  value
0     obj1      2
1     obj2      4
2     obj3      2
3     obj4      1
```

Comment: thanks @Mark, but the column names are not subject to be just obj. They can be anything. I used obj1, obj2, etc. as example.

Comment: @AccLok Ah, gotcha.  Hopefully that code can help.  I was just working on reshaping some dataframes, so this was a fun question to try and answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the efforts Mark! Appreciate it!